# how to convert these 7-segment decoder to boolean expression

Tags: logic, truthtable

how to convert these 7-segment decoder to boolean expression??

```
  BCD              7-Segment decoder     
A B C D            a b c d e f g
0 0 0 0            0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1            1 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 1 0            0 0 1 0 0 1 0
0 0 1 1            0 0 0 0 1 1 0
0 1 0 0            1 0 0 1 1 0 0 
0 1 0 1            0 1 0 0 1 0 0 
0 1 1 0            0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 1            0 0 0 1 1 1 1 
1 0 0 0            0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 1            0 0 0 0 1 0 0
```

Comment: Dlamblin, I don't know how to do these things with the truth table? but I think Its  clear after you edited it. about the homework , I swear to you it's not a homework, it's a problem that I couldn't put a Boolean expression for it

Comment: Yes, I edited it because I realized after my comment that you were pretty new. I'll take your word that it's not homework, so if you do edit it, I'd just add some context [especially implementation details like language and what you've done so far] and generalize a tad in the title, like "Converting a truthtable to a boolean expression"

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a [karnough map](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map).

You'll need to use one for each result column, so 7 4x4 tables.

There are even a few karough map generators on the web that you can use.